# MySQL: Select duplicates where another column is different?

Tags: mysql

I am already selecting the duplicates using the following query:

```
SELECT user_id FROM group_memberships GROUP BY `user_id` HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

But I want to take it a bit further. I want to check the `group_id` column on the `group_memberships`  table, and only fetch records where `user_id` is a duplicate but the duplicates have two or more different `group_id` column values.

So essentially only select users that belong to two different groups. I have many rows which are for the same group.

Example:

```
user_id        group_id
1              5
1              5
2              5
2              6
```

Should only return user_id 2 because 1's duplicates are the same group.

Answer (score 1):

Try, [sql_fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a48f2/4/0)

```
SELECT user_id FROM group_memberships 
               GROUP BY `user_id` 
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(group_id)) >= 2
```

Comment: @KailaniKailani Either no such rows or you did something incorrectly.